# How to implement expo push notification in react native with nodejs server

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I am working on an app which needs push notification. I haven't used push notification before and I am no idea how to implement this with nodejs server. Any one please help me to understand how to implement this in server as well.

For react native side I have gone through the docs But still I am not so sure how to make it work with server side.

Please Help me understand this.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to use the expo-notification module to get the token of your smartphone.

After that, you can use https://expo.io/notifications (the expo push notification tool) to check (test) whether it works.

But this is just the 1st step. It only works when you are testing (running) your app as an Expo app.

To actually use push notification in standalone APPs (iOS and Android), you need to

1. Apply for a firebase FCM account so that you can put the necessary credentials into your expo json file , so that when your `Android App` is generated and put into google play store, you can still perform push notification
2. For `iOS App`, there is no need to worry, just make sure when you submit to Apple Store you have ticked in your developer account this App requires push notification permission. The other things will be handled by Apple and Expo.

On the other hand, for sure you will not every time want to use the expo push notification tool to send notifications to your app. If you are using PHP, you can use the following codes to send push notification:

```
 <?php

    $payload = array(
        'to' => 'ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]',
        'sound' => 'default',
        'body' => 'hello',
    );

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "host: exp.host"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

On the other hand, you said you want to use nodjs server to do the job, then please refer to the following

https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node

sample codes as follows:

```
import { Expo } from 'expo-server-sdk';

// Create a new Expo SDK client
// optionally providing an access token if you have enabled push security
let expo = new Expo({ accessToken: process.env.EXPO_ACCESS_TOKEN });

// Create the messages that you want to send to clients
let messages = [];
for (let pushToken of somePushTokens) {
  // Each push token looks like ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

  // Check that all your push tokens appear to be valid Expo push tokens
  if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken)) {
    console.error(`Push token ${pushToken} is not a valid Expo push token`);
    continue;
  }

  // Construct a message (see https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/)
  messages.push({
    to: pushToken,
    sound: 'default',
    body: 'This is a test notification',
    data: { withSome: 'data' },
  })
}

// The Expo push notification service accepts batches of notifications so
// that you don't need to send 1000 requests to send 1000 notifications. We
// recommend you batch your notifications to reduce the number of requests
// and to compress them (notifications with similar content will get
// compressed).
let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
let tickets = [];
(async () => {
  // Send the chunks to the Expo push notification service. There are
  // different strategies you could use. A simple one is to send one chunk at a
  // time, which nicely spreads the load out over time:
  for (let chunk of chunks) {
    try {
      let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
      console.log(ticketChunk);
      tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
      // NOTE: If a ticket contains an error code in ticket.details.error, you
      // must handle it appropriately. The error codes are listed in the Expo
      // documentation:
      // https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#individual-errors
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
})();

...

// Later, after the Expo push notification service has delivered the
// notifications to Apple or Google (usually quickly, but allow the the service
// up to 30 minutes when under load), a "receipt" for each notification is
// created. The receipts will be available for at least a day; stale receipts
// are deleted.
//
// The ID of each receipt is sent back in the response "ticket" for each
// notification. In summary, sending a notification produces a ticket, which
// contains a receipt ID you later use to get the receipt.
//
// The receipts may contain error codes to which you must respond. In
// particular, Apple or Google may block apps that continue to send
// notifications to devices that have blocked notifications or have uninstalled
// your app. Expo does not control this policy and sends back the feedback from
// Apple and Google so you can handle it appropriately.
let receiptIds = [];
for (let ticket of tickets) {
  // NOTE: Not all tickets have IDs; for example, tickets for notifications
  // that could not be enqueued will have error information and no receipt ID.
  if (ticket.id) {
    receiptIds.push(ticket.id);
  }
}

let receiptIdChunks = expo.chunkPushNotificationReceiptIds(receiptIds);
(async () => {
  // Like sending notifications, there are different strategies you could use
  // to retrieve batches of receipts from the Expo service.
  for (let chunk of receiptIdChunks) {
    try {
      let receipts = await expo.getPushNotificationReceiptsAsync(chunk);
      console.log(receipts);

      // The receipts specify whether Apple or Google successfully received the
      // notification and information about an error, if one occurred.
      for (let receiptId in receipts) {
        let { status, message, details } = receipts[receiptId];
        if (status === 'ok') {
          continue;
        } else if (status === 'error') {
          console.error(
            `There was an error sending a notification: ${message}`
          );
          if (details && details.error) {
            // The error codes are listed in the Expo documentation:
            // https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#individual-errors
            // You must handle the errors appropriately.
            console.error(`The error code is ${details.error}`);
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is a great, detailed answer. I am implementing push notifications tomorrow, and just got my expo token working and found the testing tool through this answer. Will follow your advice for the Nodejs implementation as well!